# Cómo puedo hacer fetch sin tener problemas de cors policy con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors

Tengo una archivo html que hace una petición fetch de una imagen, pero me marca error CORS policy. ¿Cómo puedo evitar este error?
El archivo HTML lo abro en el navegador de mi computadora de forma local, y la imagen está en la misma carpeta que el archivo HTML.
(No quiero abrir el archivo usando el live server de VSC).

De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda!!

```
 <script>
    fetch('imagen.jpeg').then(res => console.log(res))
</script>
```

Me marca estos errores:

> Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/Users/Nueva%20carpeta/imagen.jpeg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Answer (score 0):

Hay que traducir los errores si no se sabe inglés, te esta diciendo que fetch es solo para el canal Http y que no puedes apuntar a un archivo local.

En VS Code [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), pero como no lo quieres usar hazte un server en Node.

[Uso de Fetch - Referencia de la API Web | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo sin tener que usar node o el live server?

Comment: Necesitas un servidor, estás haciendo una petición http. Tal vez lo puedes subir en alguna parte y ver si lo puedes obtener. Aparte, esta bloqueado por los mismos navegadores, por eso el error del CORS, ya que es un script de una página web que esta intentado acceder a recursos locales. Igual esta la extensión [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb), pero prácticamente sería mejor usar Live Server porque ahi junto al código.